# how to run an C++ program in Android OS for Linux/Windows machine

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

How to install Android in our Computer(linux-Fedora ,Windows -XP) ,and I need to run c++ program (compiling & executing) .Please Provide the links & tell me the procedure .whether i need to install any C++ compiler like GCC,Sun compiler etc..i googled it but i dont find any crystal clear working methods guys direct me in this....

EDIT: can any one specify the links for free c++ compilers  for Android Linux /windows .

Please check this links

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid&feature=more_from_developer

https://market.android.com/details?id=GDE.Main&feature=related_apps

no where **android NDK** ..is Specified ....

Please let me know ..is there any chance of runnning c++ program in Android(with out android NDK help)

Comment: Have you tried this? http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: @Bo yeah i downloaded the software from there. but in the below ...he said ,we need toinstall Ecllipse,JDk ,etc ..and no where he said the installation process

Comment: You do not really "run" android in your computer, it runs on an android device (possibly an emulated one).  Android does not formally support c++ programs or integrate them very well, but c++ can be use as an extension to java programs.  Please rewrite your question to specify what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android developer website to know how to run android in your pc. 
[step by step installation of android sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)
This site might be helpful for you for understanding how to run native code in android.
[android ndk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)